# Decrypt AES-generated hex from aes-js(Javascript) to pycryptodome(Python)

Tags: javascript, python, aes

So im trying to decrypt a string I cryptographed with JS in Python. I used the `aes-js` library. I get this: `caba6777379a00d12dcd0447015cd4dbcba649857866072d`. This is my JS code:

```js
var key = aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes("ThisKeyIs16Bytes");
console.log(`Key (bytes): ${key}`);

var text = 'psst... this is a secret';
var textBytes = aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes(text);

var aesCtr = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.ctr(key, new aesjs.Counter(5));
var encryptedBytes = aesCtr.encrypt(textBytes);

var encryptedHex = aesjs.utils.hex.fromBytes(encryptedBytes);
console.log(`Hex: ${key}`);
```

I've tried a few things in python, but this is what I currently have:

```py
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

ciphered_data = bytearray.fromhex('caba6777379a00d12dcd0447015cd4dbcba649857866072d')
key = b'ThisKeyIs16Bytes'

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR)
original_data = cipher.decrypt(ciphered_data)
print(original_data.decode("utf-8", errors="ignore"))
```

But I just recieve a mess.`=*լ☻ve↕-:tQɊ#¶`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CTR](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/classic.html#ctr-mode) mode is used. In the Pyton code the initialization of the counter is missing, i.e. the definition of the correct start value, e.g.

```
...
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, nonce = b'', initial_value = 5)
...
```

or alternatively using a [`Counter`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html#crypto-util-counter-module) object:

```
from Crypto.Util import Counter
...
counter = Counter.new(128, initial_value = 5)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter = counter)
...
```

With one of these two changes the decryption works.